# Doom-II-like red flashing screen

Tags: command-line, compiz, xrandr

I want my screen to flash red so that it looks similar to getting hit by a rocket in Doom II, preferably using cli tools. I've seen that [redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) does something similar just way too slow so I tried using xrandr but couldn't figure out how to do what I want properly. 
Can xrandr (cli) do this and if so, how?

Also I'm using compiz. Maybe there is a way to do it with compiz using dbus-send?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a not very satisfying solution I found that blinks for .1 sec.

`sh -c 'redshift -o -t 1600:1500 -l 53:15&' ;sleep .1; redshift -l 53:15 -x`

But it would be nicer if it would phase in from red to normal like it normally does using redshift.

Edit: Well well, this'll have to do for now I guess.